# Facebook Share Button Wont Share Symbols

Tags: facebook, perl, button, share

i tried this code here to share the current page that i am on but some of the url is but off so it is sharing the wrong page. I worked out that the symbol "&" is cut out so i wonder if anyone knows how to bypass this.

The Code:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.ibidthai.com/auction.pl?category=$form{'category'}&item=$form{'item'}">Share</a>
```

The $form{'category'} and $form{'item'} is a variable in this case its category="car" and item="[]1415689774"

Comment: You will need to add more detail and post your code, the current output, and the desired output, as it is unclear what your problem is here. How is the `&` getting cut out?

Comment: Keyword: __URL encoding__

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your query parameters using [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) or some similar module/functionality:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI::Escape;

my %form = ( category => 'car', item => '[]1415689774' );

my $u = "http://www.ibidthai.com/auction.pl?category=$form{'category'}&item=$form{'item'}";

my $url = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" . uri_escape($u);

print "$url\n";
```

Outputs:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibidthai.com%2Fauction.pl%3Fcategory%3Dcar%26item%3D%5B%5D1415689774
```

Although, if you're wanting to be thorough, both your URIs should actually be encoded if there is any possibility the query params of the first could contain special characters:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

my %form = ( category => 'car', item => '[]1415689774' );

my $auction_uri = URI->new("http://www.ibidthai.com/auction.pl");
$auction_uri->query_form( category => $form{category}, item => $form{item} );

print "$auction_uri\n";

my $share_uri = URI->new('http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php');
$share_uri->query_form( u => "$auction_uri" );

print "$share_uri\n";
```

Outputs:

```
http://www.ibidthai.com/auction.pl?category=car&item=%5B%5D1415689774
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ibidthai.com%2Fauction.pl%3Fcategory%3Dcar%26item%3D%255B%255D1415689774
```